# Crashlytics does not send crash data in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, crashlytics

I'm trying to implement crashlythics into an empty project for test porpuses and even if i fully follow the official gudes [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=1&platform=ios) and [this one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#test_it_out) but i could not have much luck, after following the second guide i have this in the console log

```
2022-07-25 17:21:38.157616+0200 crashlythics test[607:149616] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2022-07-25 17:21:38.183569+0200 crashlythics test[607:149595] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 9.4.0
2022-07-25 17:21:38.183961+0200 crashlythics test[607:149616] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics] Running on iPhone12,8, 14.0.0 (18A373)
2022-07-25 17:21:38.207022+0200 crashlythics test[607:149616] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000033] Data Collection flag is not set.
2022-07-25 17:21:38.208194+0200 crashlythics test[607:149617] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Root: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/98366F06-111E-42DF-9519-A1E5D2CA50E9/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/D.Pashkov.crashlythics-test
2022-07-25 17:21:38.211229+0200 crashlythics test[607:149615] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Firebase Analytics SDK not detected. Crash-free statistics and breadcrumbs will not be reported
2022-07-25 17:21:38.211277+0200 crashlythics test[607:149615] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Automatic data collection is enabled.
2022-07-25 17:21:38.211403+0200 crashlythics test[607:149615] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Unsent reports will be uploaded at startup
Fatal error: Crash was triggered: file crashlythics_test/ContentView.swift, line 13
2022-07-25 17:21:58.490175+0200 crashlythics test[607:149595] Fatal error: Crash was triggered: file crashlythics_test/ContentView.swift, line 13
(lldb)
```

I'm not sure if the code inside the views is needed since is an empty project but just in case i'll copy past it here:

crashlythics_testApp.swift:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
  }
}

@main
struct crashlythics_testApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Crash") {
          fatalError("Crash was triggered")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The logs suggest that the Crashlytics SDK was installed and initialized correctly.

When testing, make sure you are following the steps mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#force-test-crash). Especially the part that says to stop Xcode. These would be the steps:

1. Run the app from Xcode
2. After it is running in the device/simulator, hit "Stop" in Xcode
3. Then open the app in the device and cause a test crash.
4. Run the app again from Xcode

After this, the debug logs should something like this:

```
9.3.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Packaged report with id '5caa69396c6f47479add349810a604bc' for submission
9.3.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Submitting report async
9.3.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Completed report submission with id: 5caa69396c6f47479add349810a604bc
```

These steps are required because Xcode attaches a debugger which prevents Crashlytics from getting crash data.